# React.js how to pass in index as prop to child component from this.props array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, this

New to React, so apologise in advance if my terminology is way off target.
I have a table that has a list of people in specific order. I need to be able to create a `this.props.tablePosition` value based on the index on the person in question.

`this.props` is an array in the Table component. I have the code below thats not working as I'm not exactly sure how to get the index.

```
<RankingCards {...this.props} tablePosition={this.props.indexOf(this)} />
```

Comment: Can you show the rest of the code for the component?

Comment: What do you mean by 'this.props is an array'? And you need to provide some more code.

Comment: `this.props` should be an object containing properties, so maybe `this.props.myArray` can contain an array

Comment: can you give some test case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to view rest of the code, but as per my understanding, you need this kind of flow, but correct me if I am wrong ;)

---

If you are getting the props like this, in the parent component

```
{
    tableData: [
        {name: "John", index: 1},
        {name: "David", index: 2},
        {name: "Ardhya", index: 3}
    ]
}
```

You can provide the required data to individual child components like this.

```
this.props.tableData.map(function(data){
    // do whatever processing you want to perform
    return(
        <RankingCards rawProp={data} tablePosition={data.index} key={data.index} />
    )
})
```

Inside your RankingCards component, you'll get the props other than key.

Eg. for first entity, if you print props with `console.log(this.props)`, you'll get the values in this way.

```
{
    rawProp: {name: "John", index: 1},
    tablePosition: 1
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`this.props` would refer to the Table component's properties- but if you mean you are passing in the array to the Table component, eg. `<Table personList={["John","Jeff","Joe"]} />`, then you can just use a for loop in your Table's render function:

```
    render() {
      var rankingCards = []
      var personList = this.props.personList
      for (var i = 0; i < personList.length; i++) {
        rankingCards.push(<RankingCard {...personList[i].props} tablePosition={i} />)
      }
      return(
        <RankingCardContainer>
          {rankingCards}
        </RankingCardContainer>
      )
    }
```